# Orders going to cancelled if payment not made

Tags: magento-2.1, paypal, order-status

We have a web-store that was previously using sage-pay to handle customer transactions, however after multiple issues with the service we decided to another option for PayPal Pro that is built into magento.

PayPal is working fine, however, if user adds items to their cart and then goes to check out and clicks the "continue with PayPal" button and then closes the web page or goes back, the order is added to the system and has a status of cancelled. This never happened before on the previous payment system and we are not interested in orders that the user decided not to place in the end.

How do I make orders that did not actually go through not appear?

Comment: I guess that you want like **if the user does not pay then the order does not create**.?

Comment: then use expree checkout https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-express-checkout.html or  https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/braintree.html